# PHP merge and rearrange 2 or more arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

It will be 2 or more arrays come out from foreach loop. Like following

```
array1 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1207
            [1] => 4
            [2] => haha.mp4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1208
            [1] => 4
            [2] => hehe.mp4
        )

array2
   [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1209
            [1] => 16
            [2] => SampleVideo.mp4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1210
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 295.mp4
        )
```

**I want to get same index value from these 2 arrays** and merge these array like that.

```
**FinalArray = array1[0],array2[0],array1[1],array2[1]**
```

E.g

```
FinalArray

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1207
            [1] => 4
            [2] => haha.mp4
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1209
            [1] => 16
            [2] => SampleVideo.mp4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1208
            [1] => 4
            [2] => hehe.mp4
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1210
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 295.mp4
        )
```

please help how to get same index values and merge that 2 arrays. Thanks

Comment: put your foreach loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may achieve this by only one loop using [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) and [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge) as follows,

```
$array1 = array(
    0 => [0 => 1207, 1 => 4, 2 => "haha.mp4"],
    1 => [0 => 1208, 1 => 4, 2 => "hehe.mp4"],
);

$array2 = array(
    0 => [0 => 1209, 1 => 16, 2 => "SampleVideo.mp4"],
    1 => [0 => 1210, 1 => 16, 2 => "295.mp4"],
);

// here I assume that the following array is the output of your foreach loop
$array = [$array1, $array2];
$list = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $list = array_merge($list, array_column($array, $key));
}

print_r($list);
```

live demo: https://3v4l.org/2chf5

Answer (score 0):

sandy, I have come to rescue you from nonsense.  All methods on this page are using either too many loops or too many functions.  Best practice would look like this:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4d14e95db498fa160938c1ec8c2c0c5553f3dd7))

```
$array1 = array(
    0 => [0 => 1207, 1 => 4, 2 => "haha.mp4"],
    1 => [0 => 1208, 1 => 4, 2 => "hehe.mp4"],
);

$array2 = array(
    0 => [0 => 1209, 1 => 16, 2 => "SampleVideo.mp4"],
    1 => [0 => 1210, 1 => 16, 2 => "295.mp4"],
);

foreach($array1 as $k=>$v){
    $result[]=$v;
    // if $array2 always has a matching key:
    $result[]=$array2[$k];
    // if it is possible that $array2 doesn't have a matching key:
    // if(isset($array2[$k]){$result[]=$array2[$k];}
    //... if you have more arrays to include, just repeat like: $result[]=$array3[$k];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1207,
    1 => 4,
    2 => 'haha.mp4',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 1209,
    1 => 16,
    2 => 'SampleVideo.mp4',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 1208,
    1 => 4,
    2 => 'hehe.mp4',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 1210,
    1 => 16,
    2 => '295.mp4',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

From:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't want simply merge these arrays. I want to merge same index value like following.
FinalArray = array1[0],array2[0],array1[1],array2[1]

Comment: Then I guess you will have to loop through them using foreach($key => $value) and arrange them manually

Comment: Yes, I know here my loop. but need to be dynamic
foreach ($out as $key => $value) {

          if($key == 0) {
            $room0 = array_merge($room0,$value);
          }
          if($key == 1) {
            $room1 = array_merge($room1,$value);
          }
        }

Answer (score -1):

To get finalArray with elements order `array0[0],array1[0],array0[1],array1[1]` first calculate `$max_elements` and then perform nested loop with check if element with `$i` in that array exist:

```
$arrays = [$array0, $array1];
$max_elements = 0;
foreach($arrays as $array){
    $max_elements = max($max_elements, count($array));
}
$merged = []
for($i = 0; $i < $max_elements; $i++){
    foreach($arrays as $array){
        if($array[$i]){
            $merged[] = $array[$i];
        }
    }
}
```